# I am using Realm Mobile Platform i want to display same data on web and Mobile both

Tags: mysql, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am developing an app by using Realm Mobile Platform. Want to have real-time data transfer between the device, Which is working completely fine by using Realm Mobile Platform. But I am not able to get the data and display it on the server(Website).
Example:  Slack
You can access slack from the different phone and at the same time, you can access it on the web browser.

I want to perform the same kind of feature using Realm Mobile Platform.

Is there any way to import realm Database into MySQL? By this Way, I can show the data on the server as well.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I am also looking for the same feature for my next application.Please share the solution when you will get it.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your website backend is node.js based you can open the same realms on server with the node.js version of realm (https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/).

Comment: So there is not other solution if you aren't using node.js?

Comment: You can also use C# serverside.